# Exim TLS error while reading file cert=REMOTE_SMTP_/etc/exim4/exim.crt

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, exim, exim4

After a week of installing and configuring my **first** Linux (mail)server (Debian 9, Exim 4, Dovecot) the TLS encrypted communication with my client works. Sending, receiving and DKIM signing also work.

Except for this problem I find in my logs when **sending** mails:

> 2017-07-22 20:56:08 1dYzZQ-0005fx-6J H=verifier.port25.com [38.95.177.125] TLS error on connection (cert/key setup: cert=REMOTE_SMTP_/etc/exim4/exim.crt key=REMOTE_SMTP_/etc/exim4/exim.crt): Error while reading file.

> 2017-07-22 20:56:08 1dYzZQ-0005fx-6J TLS session failure: delivering unencrypted to verifier.port25.com [38.95.177.125] (not in hosts_require_tls)

The **REMOTE_SMTP_** part doesn't seem to belong there. Also key should point to a **.key** file I guess.

`03_exim4-config_tlsoptions` seems to be fine.

Editing `30_exim4-config_remote_smtp` may solve the first issue `("REMOTE_SMTP_")`, but it should be working anyway:

```
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
tls_certificate = REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
.endif
.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_PRIVATEKEY
tls_privatekey = REMOTE_SMTP_PRIVATEKEY
.endif
```

Where does the error come from and how to solve it?

Any advice or explanation would be highly appreciated.

**Additional research, didn't find anything:**

Full path to key and certificate hasn't been used in a wrong way by me:

```
root@example:/etc/exim4# grep -r exim4/exim /etc/exim4/
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:# /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template is only used with the non-split
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE = /etc/exim4/exim.crt
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:MAIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY = /etc/exim4/exim.key
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE = /etc/exim4/exim.crt
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:MAIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY = /etc/exim4/exim.key
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/01_exim4-config_listmacrosdefs:# /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template is only used with the non-split
```

Exim may default to CONFDIR/exim.crt

```
root@example:~# grep -r exim.crt /etc/exim4/
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:#                          CONFDIR/exim.crt if unset
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE = /etc/exim4/exim.crt
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:#                          CONFDIR/exim.crt if unset
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE = /etc/exim4/exim.crt
```

and CONFDIR/exim.key of course

```
root@example:~# grep -r CONFDIR/exim /etc/exim4/
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:#                          CONFDIR/exim.crt if unset
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:#                          CONFDIR/exim.key if unset
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:#                          CONFDIR/exim.crt if unset
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:#                          CONFDIR/exim.key if unset
```

CONFDIR is here

```
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/01_exim4-config_listmacrosdefs:CONFDIR = /etc/exim4
```

So much for the first issue. Regarding the second issue (use of .crt instead of .key) I can't find a misuse of MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE

```
root@example:~# grep -r MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE  /etc/exim4/
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:#   MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE - path to certificate file,
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:.ifndef MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:tls_certificate = MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE = /etc/exim4/exim.crt
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:TLS_CERTIFICATE = MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:#   MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE - path to certificate file,
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:.ifndef MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE = /etc/exim4/exim.crt
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:tls_certificate = MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE
```

Same for tls_certificate.

tls_certificate = MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY looks a bit off, but is the default value in a new installation.

```
root@example:~# grep -r tls_certificate  /etc/exim4/
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:MAIN_LOG_SELECTOR = +smtp_protocol_error +smtp_syntax_error +tls_certificate_verified +tls_peerdn
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:tls_certificate = MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:tls_certificate = MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:tls_certificate = REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:tls_certificate = REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_TLS_CERTIFICATE
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:tls_certificate = MAIN_TLS_CERTKEY
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/03_exim4-config_tlsoptions:tls_certificate = MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/01_exim4-config_listmacrosdefs:MAIN_LOG_SELECTOR = +smtp_protocol_error +smtp_syntax_error +tls_certificate_verified +tls_peerdn
/etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp:tls_certificate = REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
/etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp_smarthost:tls_certificate = REMOTE_SMTP_SMARTHOST_TLS_CERTIFICATE
```

Search for REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE

```
root@example:/var/log/exim4# grep -r REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE /etc/exim4/
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:tls_certificate = REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
/etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp:.ifdef REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
/etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp:tls_certificate = REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
```

Updated permissions

```
root@example:/etc/exim4# ls -l exim.crt exim.key
-rw-r----- 1 root Debian-exim 1066 Jul 21  2017 exim.crt
-rw-r----- 1 root Debian-exim 1708 Jul 21  2017 exim.key
```

Comment: It has been four months now and I still have no idea

Answer (score -1):

The exim4 certificate and key files need to have owner and mode set in a strict way, otherwise exim will not read it, instead it will give this *Error while reading file* error message during the *cert/key setup* phase. The exact owner and mode are:

```
root@hostname:/etc/exim4# ls -l exim.crt exim.key
-rw-r----- 1 root Debian-exim 2224 mag 30 17:13 exim.crt
-rw-r----- 1 root Debian-exim 1704 mag 30 17:12 exim.key
```

Another option is that your `REMOTE_SMTP_/etc/exim4/exim.crt` file is a mangled macro. Do you have any `TLS_CERTIFICATE` macro that is substitued in the second part of `REMOTE_SMTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE` macro?